# Send email from database using phpmailer

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmailer

I'm currently working on a php mysql base system that will send email to multiple recipients from database . Im already search in forum and a lot of answer is using loop to email recipient. And then i'm try using looping in email recipient,but just able to send 1 email (although in database have a 5 or more email recipient).Can you tell me ,where my code is wrong?
Below is my code :

```
function send_message( $from, $to, $subject, $message_content )
{
    require_once "function.php";
    require_once( 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php' );

    //Initiate the mailer class
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    //Check to see if SMTP creds have been defined
    if( defined( 'SMTP_USER' ) && defined( 'SMTP_PASS' ) && defined( 'SMTP_LOCATION' ) && defined( 'SMTP_PORT' ) )
    {
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host = SMTP_LOCATION;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Port = SMTP_PORT;
        $mail->Username = SMTP_USER;
        $mail->Password = SMTP_PASS;

        if( defined( 'DEBUG' ) && DEBUG )
        {
            $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;   
        }
    }

    //Set the sender and receiver email addresses

    $alamatmail=get_mail();
    foreach ( $alamatmail as $datamail):
        $from="xxx@gmail.com";
        $to=$datamail['email'];
            //Include the phpmailer files
            $mail->SetFrom( $from, "" );

            //We 'can' send to an array, in which case you'll want to explode at comma or line break
            if( is_array( $to ) )
            {
                foreach( $to as $i )
                {
                    $mail->addAddress( $i );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $mail->AddAddress( $to, "" );
            }

            //Set the message subject
            $mail->Subject = $subject;

            //Add the message header
            $message = file_get_contents( 'email-templates/email-header.php' );

            //Add the message body
            $message .= file_get_contents( 'email-templates/email-body.php' );

            //Add the message footer content
            $message .= file_get_contents( 'email-templates/email-footer.php' );

            //Replace the codetags with the message contents
            $replacements = array(
                '({message_subject})' => $subject, 
                '({message_body})' => nl2br( stripslashes( $message_content ) ),
            );
            $message = preg_replace( array_keys( $replacements ), array_values( $replacements ), $message );

            //Make the generic plaintext separately due to lots of css and tables
            $plaintext = $message_content;
            $plaintext = strip_tags( stripslashes( $plaintext ), '<p><br><h2><h3><h1><h4>' );
            $plaintext = str_replace( array( '<p>', '<br />', '<br>', '<h1>', '<h2>', '<h3>', '<h4>' ), PHP_EOL, $plaintext );
            $plaintext = str_replace( array( '</p>', '</h1>', '</h2>', '</h3>', '</h4>' ), '', $plaintext );
            $plaintext = html_entity_decode( stripslashes( $plaintext ) );

            //Send the message as HTML
            $mail->MsgHTML( stripslashes( $message ) ); 
            //Set the plain text version just in case
            $mail->AltBody = $plaintext;
            $failed_error="email gagal dikirim";
            //Display success or error messages
            if( !$mail->Send() )
            {
                return 'Message send failure: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                   return $failed_error;
            }

            else
            {
                //You'll usually want to just return true, but for the purposes of this
                //Example I'm returning the message contents
             //   return $message;
                return print_r($alamatmail);
            }
            endforeach;

}
```

Comment: What do you get, if you do `var_dump($alamatmail);` ?

Comment: they are returning array value 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [email] => y.wsetyawan@test.co.id ) [1] => Array ( [email] => xxx@gmail.com ) [2] => Array ( [email] => xx2@gmail.com ) )
and the result is right,

Comment: yup,i'm trying to do it.

Comment: @yosafatwahyusetyawan are you sending the same email to all the emails?

Comment: You don't need the `if..else` block inside your `foreach` loop. Replace the complete block with `$mail->addAddress( $to, "" );`
Note, that first `a` is smaller in `addAddress`.

Comment: yes,gideon. I'm trying to do send same email to all email in database.

Comment: okay , prerak . I will try trick as you suggested

Comment: I'm already trying ,your solution,prerak. But i'm still get same result T_T

Comment: You've based your code on an outdated example. Why not start with some [known-good code](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) that you already have a copy of?

Comment: since ,that's code have a good example to using html template in phpmailer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are sending the same mail to all the recipients there is no need to iterate over the message over and over again. All you need to do is set the sender and then add all your recipients to the addAddress array and then end the loop.

After that you just build you mail body and execute the send function.

You can use this:

```
<?
function send_message( $from, $to, $subject, $message_content )
{
    require_once "function.php";
    require_once( 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php' );

    //Initiate the mailer class
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    //Check to see if SMTP creds have been defined
    if( defined( 'SMTP_USER' ) && defined( 'SMTP_PASS' ) && defined( 'SMTP_LOCATION' ) && defined( 'SMTP_PORT' ) )
    {
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host = SMTP_LOCATION;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Port = SMTP_PORT;
        $mail->Username = SMTP_USER;
        $mail->Password = SMTP_PASS;

        if( defined( 'DEBUG' ) && DEBUG )
        {
            $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;   
        }
    }

    $mail->SetFrom( 'xxx@gmail.com', "" );


    //Set the sender and receiver email addresses
    $alamatmail = get_mail();

    foreach ($alamatmail as $datamail) {
        $to = $datamail['email'];

        //We 'can' send to an array, in which case you'll want to explode at comma or line break
        if(is_array($to)) {
            foreach( $to as $i ) {
                $mail->AddAddress($i, "" );
            }
        }
        else {
            $mail->AddAddress($to, "" );
        }
    }

    //Set the message subject
    $mail->Subject = $subject;

    //Add the message header
    $message = file_get_contents( 'email-templates/email-header.php' );

    //Add the message body
    $message .= file_get_contents( 'email-templates/email-body.php' );

    //Add the message footer content
    $message .= file_get_contents( 'email-templates/email-footer.php' );

    //Replace the codetags with the message contents
    $replacements = array(
        '({message_subject})' => $subject, 
        '({message_body})' => nl2br( stripslashes( $message_content ) ),
    );
    $message = preg_replace( array_keys( $replacements ), array_values( $replacements ), $message );

    //Make the generic plaintext separately due to lots of css and tables
    $plaintext = $message_content;
    $plaintext = strip_tags( stripslashes( $plaintext ), '<p><br><h2><h3><h1><h4>' );
    $plaintext = str_replace( array( '<p>', '<br />', '<br>', '<h1>', '<h2>', '<h3>', '<h4>' ), PHP_EOL, $plaintext );
    $plaintext = str_replace( array( '</p>', '</h1>', '</h2>', '</h3>', '</h4>' ), '', $plaintext );
    $plaintext = html_entity_decode( stripslashes( $plaintext ) );

    //Send the message as HTML
    $mail->MsgHTML(stripslashes($message));

    //Set the plain text version just in case
    $mail->AltBody = $plaintext;
    $failed_error="email gagal dikirim";

    //Display success or error messages
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        return 'Message send failure: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . $failed_error;
    } else {
        //You'll usually want to just return true, but for the purposes of this
        //Example I'm returning the message contents
     //   return $message;
        return print_r($alamatmail);
    }
}
```

Since the first one includes all recipients in the to field in each email you can use this (I have ignored the error section so you can add it manually):

```html
<?
function send_message( $from, $to, $subject, $message_content )
{
    require_once "function.php";
    require_once( 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php' );

    //Initiate the mailer class
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    //Check to see if SMTP creds have been defined
    if( defined( 'SMTP_USER' ) && defined( 'SMTP_PASS' ) && defined( 'SMTP_LOCATION' ) && defined( 'SMTP_PORT' ) )
    {
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host = SMTP_LOCATION;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Port = SMTP_PORT;
        $mail->Username = SMTP_USER;
        $mail->Password = SMTP_PASS;

        if( defined( 'DEBUG' ) && DEBUG )
        {
            $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;   
        }
    }

    $mail->SetFrom( 'xxx@gmail.com', "" );


    //Set the sender and receiver email addresses
    $alamatmail = get_mail();

    //Set the message subject
    $mail->Subject = $subject;

    //Add the message header
    $message = file_get_contents( 'email-templates/email-header.php' );

    //Add the message body
    $message .= file_get_contents( 'email-templates/email-body.php' );

    //Add the message footer content
    $message .= file_get_contents( 'email-templates/email-footer.php' );

    //Replace the codetags with the message contents
    $replacements = array(
        '({message_subject})' => $subject, 
        '({message_body})' => nl2br( stripslashes( $message_content ) ),
    );
    $message = preg_replace( array_keys( $replacements ), array_values( $replacements ), $message );

    //Make the generic plaintext separately due to lots of css and tables
    $plaintext = $message_content;
    $plaintext = strip_tags( stripslashes( $plaintext ), '<p><br><h2><h3><h1><h4>' );
    $plaintext = str_replace( array( '<p>', '<br />', '<br>', '<h1>', '<h2>', '<h3>', '<h4>' ), PHP_EOL, $plaintext );
    $plaintext = str_replace( array( '</p>', '</h1>', '</h2>', '</h3>', '</h4>' ), '', $plaintext );
    $plaintext = html_entity_decode( stripslashes( $plaintext ) );

    //Send the message as HTML
    $mail->MsgHTML(stripslashes($message));

    //Set the plain text version just in case
    $mail->AltBody = $plaintext;
    $failed_error="email gagal dikirim";

    foreach ($alamatmail as $datamail) {
        $to = $datamail['email'];

        //We 'can' send to an array, in which case you'll want to explode at comma or line break
        if(is_array($to)) {
            foreach( $to as $i ) {
                $mail2 = clone $mail;
                $mail2->AddAddress($i, "");
                $mail2->send();
            }
        }
        else {
            $mail2 = clone $mail;
            $mail2->AddAddress($to, "");
            $mail2->send();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this should work, a hint why it works (and the original does not) would be a good idea, would it not?

Comment: Okay Burki I will add it

Comment: Actually, you should still send your e-mail to each recipient separately.

Comment: The problem with this approach (apart from it not addressing the question why the original didn't work) is that you are disclosing other people's email addresses to all the recipients, which is not a good idea.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you Burki

Comment: In this case may i suggest you edit your answer accordingly, lest a future visitor of the site uses it without reading the comments.

Comment: Okay then I will add the other as an option

Comment: in which line i'm disclosing other people email address to all recipient ?
i'm really want to know,burki T_T
Thanks for your advice ,gideon ,markus and Burki

Comment: When you use addAddress, each email will contain all the emails that received the mail so I'm now editing my answer to show you how to send emails without disclosing other peoples email

Comment: Okay,thanks for doing that. I'm sure that's will help me and other visitor in the future ^_^

Answer (score 3):

in the success case, your function is ended after the first iteration by

```
return print_r($alamatmail);
```

This line exits the function. The next iteration will not be called.

Move this line after

```
endforeach;
```

and your code should work (only it will not print the whole mails. You need to handle that separately)

Comment: i'm just now using try using your solution,burki. But i'm still get same result. 
The email just send to 1 recipient .

Comment: @yosafatwahyusetyawan did you move the `return` statement outside your `foreach` loop?

Comment: return is for 'returning' the result of the function so execution of the function ends whenever it is reached. Your line 'return print_r($alamatmail);' serves no purpose as print_r outputs the veriable to the screen so your effectively saying 'return an output to the screen' which won't work. loose the return and just use print_r($alamatmail);

Comment: Burki  : yup ,i'm move the return as you suggested ^^ . 
Horaland : Thank you ,for your suggestion . I will use your suggestion in the future ^^